# Can only run Eclipse from command line. Help?

Tags: eclipse

I just installed JRE and Eclipse, but every time I try to run the Eclipse application, it shows the splash screen and then closes quickly. For now, I created a batch file that runs:

```
eclipse -vm c:\java\bin\java.exe
```

Why is my application showing the splash screen and then closing? Or is there a way to run the batch script, but keep the command prompt and java prompt running in the background out of view?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to your eclipse.ini

```
-vm
C:\java\bin\java.exe
```

This link should be useful too: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher